# Mobaxterm ssh browser doesn't load and uploads get stuck at 0%

Tags: upload, remote-access, mobaxterm

As said on the title, when connecting to my university's server using mobaxterm, the ssh browser doesn't show anything and when I put the mouse on it, it appears as loading(the mouse with the blue circle). Also when I try uploading a file, it gets stuck at 0%.

I've seen other threads with the same stuck at 0% problem, but the solutions like changing from sftp to scp or reloading the terminal don't work on me and no one mentioned the ssh browser blank and loading so I'm guessing this is a different issue from the ones being discussed in the other posts.

P.D: Don't know if this is gonna help identifyng the problem but i'm using a private key to connect to the computer on my university. If you need more info about what I'm using/settings please ask.

Comment: Why using sftp wont work? since ssh works. you would use same user/password/sshFile and port. it's way more stable this way.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I was torn by this problem until I understood where it came from...
This problem is because there is a non-English file path name in the drag and drop path, that's why it stays at zero percent